# Two message box returns

Tags: excel

please help me to edit this code. I have a excel workbook that I need to save in a folder of my choosing as both a xlsm file and a PDF. After adding all the information on my spreadsheet that needs to be entered in order to use the range as reference and choosing the folder the files save, but then the message box "Kon nie document stoor nie." pops up. if it saves successfully only the message box "Copy Gemaak" needs to show!
thanks for the help!

```
Sub Combined()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim fileSaveName As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

     fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Kwotasie - " &       Range("H14").Value)
    If VarType(fileSaveName) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub


    ' Save as XLSM
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    ' Save as PDF
    Range("a1:I51").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fileSaveName _
        , Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _     
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

       If myFile <> "False" Then
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
              Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
              OpenAfterPublish:=False

           MsgBox "Copy gemaak."

         End If

       exitHandler:
          Exit Sub
      errHandler:
         MsgBox "Kon nie dokumente stoor nie."
          Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you're issue is that your macro is only ever displaying the `MsgBox` for "Kon nie dokumente stoor nie".

Assuming that's right, it is a little hard to tell what's the issue since your VBA is on the messy side. Best guess is that since you never set `ws`, the attempt to save the worksheet invokes `errHandler`.

Some clean up you'd want to do in this case:

1. you should just declare and use `FileSaveName` as a string. If there's any way it's getting set to a Boolean something weird would seem to be going on (at least based off what you've told us so far).
2. get rid of `Exit Handler`. The only place it's used is if you make it to `ErrHandler`. If that happens, the `End Sub` at the end of your code will close things out just fine, no need to use an `Exit Sub` at all.
3. add an `End If` after your first `If`
4. use indenting to show what code is dependent on the `If` statements

To elaborate on my answer; given all the above, I'm kind of stabbing in the dark, but it looks like `myFile` should never be `"False"` (the `if` should cast `myFile` to a string, and since the variable is never set it's value is `""`). So in that case, the the attempt to save `ws` as a PDF is used, and fails since `ws` is also never set, meaning Excel has no idea what you're trying to save. Thus you get kicked to `errHandler`.

Hope that helps. If not, please elaborate on the behavior you are seeing, and if possible, update the original question with cleaned up code.